# How do I link checkbox with file open dialog box & display the details of the file opened in GUI using python tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to create a GUI using python tkinter code, in which it must include: checkbox, file open dialog box, description/details box & submit button

The file open dialog box should get opened only when the checkbox of it is checked in the GUI.

For example, there are 2 checkboxes 
1. Soil 2. Weather

Only when the Soil checkbox is checked the file open box should get opened and it has to print the path of the opened file in the console & repeat the same for Weather.

And the details of the selected file should get displayed on the right side of the interface.

At last a submit button needs to be included. After clicking submit button the interface should close.

```
from tkinter import * #imports
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

win = Tk()            #create instance

win.title("Spatialization of DSSAT model")

w = 160 # width for the Tk root
h = 100 # height for the Tk root

# get screen width and height
ws = win.winfo_screenwidth() # width of the screen
hs = win.winfo_screenheight() # height of the screen

# calculate x and y coordinates for the Tk root window
x = (ws/2) - (w/2)
y = (hs/2) - (h/2)

# set the dimensions of the screen
# and where it is placed
win.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))

def var_states():
    print("soil: %d, \nweather:%d" % (var1.get(), var2.get()))

Label(win, text="Select:").grid(row=0, sticky=W)
var1 = IntVar()
Checkbutton(win, text = "soil", variable=var1).grid(row=1, sticky=W)
var2 = IntVar()
Checkbutton(win, text = "weather", variable=var2).grid(row=2, sticky=W)

MyButton1 = Button(win, text="Submit", width=10)
MyButton1.grid(row=10, column=10)

Tk().withdraw()
filename1 = askopenfilename()
print(filename1)

Tk().withdraw()
filename2 = askopenfilename()
print(filename2)

win.mainloop()           #start the GUI
```

Comment: So you want if anyone checks any of the `Checkbutton` then `askopenfilename()` should be called. and the file path should be printed in console?

Comment: Exactly and also I want to show the details of the selected file in "description box" in the right side of the GUI @Partho63

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `command=someFunction` for check-buttons and submit-button and then in `someFunction()` you need to write what you want to be done when that button is clicked.

Try this:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

win = Tk()

win.title("Spatialization of DSSAT model")

w = 160
h = 100

ws = win.winfo_screenwidth()
hs = win.winfo_screenheight()

x = (ws/2) - (w/2)
y = (hs/2) - (h/2)

win.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))

def forCheckbutton1():
    filename1 = askopenfilename()
    print(filename1)

def forCheckbutton2():
    filename2 = askopenfilename()
    print(filename2)

def forMuButton1():
    win.destroy()

def var_states():
    print("soil: %d, \nweather:%d" % (MyVar1.get(), MyVar2.get()))

MyLabel1 = Label(win, text="Select:")
MyLabel1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)

MyVar1 = IntVar()
MyVar2 = IntVar()

MyCheckbutton1 = Checkbutton(win, text="soil", variable=MyVar1, command=forCheckbutton1)
MyCheckbutton1.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)
MyCheckbutton2 = Checkbutton(win, text="weather", variable=MyVar2, command=forCheckbutton2)
MyCheckbutton2.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)

MyButton1 = Button(win, text="Submit", width=10, command=forMuButton1)
MyButton1.grid(row=3, column=0)

win.mainloop()
```

and for displaying information you can add a frame and show your desired information on the frame.